# MVC - Exibir mensagens a partir do controlador

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Dentro da minha aplicação MVC temos várias situações em que, dependendo das regras de negócio da função, várias mensagens devem ser exibidas para o usuário.

Atualmente estamos utilizando a biblioteca Jquery "Toastr" para exibir as mensagens ao usuário. O desenvolvimento está da seguinte forma:

1) Definição das configurações da mensagem (MensagemAlerta.cshtml)

```
@helper MostrarMensagensAlerta(Alerta alerta)
{
    if (alerta != null)
    {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            window.toastr.options.closeButton = '@alerta.MostrarBotaoFechar';
            window.toastr.options.newestOnTop = '@alerta.MostrarNoTopo';

            @foreach (Aperam.Biblioteca.Util.Base.Entidades.MensagemAlerta mensagem in alerta.MensagensAlerta)
            {
                string tipoAlerta = mensagem.TipoAlerta.ToString("F").ToLower();                
                @: var opcoes = { /* Adicione atributos específidos dos alertas Toastr aqui */ };

                @:opcoes.closeButton = true;
                @:opcoes.progressBar = true;
                @:opcoes.positionClass = "toast-top-right";

                if (mensagem.ManterAlerta)
                {
                    @:opcoes.timeOut = 0;
                    @:opcoes.extendedTimeout = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    @:opcoes.timeOut = 10000;
                    @:opcoes.extendedTimeOut = 10000;
                }

                var texto = mensagem.Mensagem.Replace("\r\n", "<br /> ").Replace("\r", "<br /> ").Replace("\n", "<br /> ").Replace("'", "");
                @:window.toastr['@tipoAlerta']('@(new HtmlString(texto))', '@mensagem.Titulo', opcoes);
            }
        });
    </script>
    }
}
```

2) Partial view adicionada à pagina principal (_Mensagem.cshtml):

```html
@if (TempData.ContainsKey("Alerta"))
{
  Alerta alerta = TempData["Alerta"] as Alerta;
  @MensagemAlerta.MostrarMensagensAlerta(alerta);
}
```

3) Dentro da master page, adicionei a div relacionada a partial view de mensagens:

```
<div id="div-mensagens">
  @Html.Partial("_Mensagem")
</div>
```

4) Dentro do controlador, tenho um método que adiciona as mensagens via TempData:

```
public MensagemAlerta AdicionarMensagemAlerta(string mensagem, TipoAlerta tipoAlerta = TipoAlerta.Info)
    {
        string titulo = string.Empty;

        switch (tipoAlerta)
        {
            case TipoAlerta.Error:
                titulo = "Erro";
                break;
            case TipoAlerta.Info:
            case TipoAlerta.Success:
                titulo = "Informação";
                break;
            case TipoAlerta.Warning:
                titulo = "Alerta";
                break;
        }

        Alerta alerta = TempData["Alerta"] as Alerta;
        alerta = alerta ?? new Alerta();

        var mensagemAlerta = alerta.AdicionarMensagemAlerta(titulo, mensagem, tipoAlerta);
        TempData["Alerta"] = alerta;
        return mensagemAlerta;

    }
```

A inclusão e visualização das mensagens acontece corretamente quando a requisição é via POST e a página principal (_Layout.cshtml) é carregada novamente.

O problema é quando as chamadas são realizadas via ajax e apenas a partial view é carregada. Nestas condições, como a partial view "_Mensagem.cshtml" não é recarregada, as mensagens não são exibidas.

Outro problema é que meu tratamento de erro padrão também utiliza essa função para exibir as mensagens. Desta forma, quando ocorre um erro a partir de uma chamada ajax, a mensagem só é exibida quando o usuário recarrega a página completa.

Uma solução paliativa que estou utilizando é, ao final de toda chama ajax, realizar uma nova chamada ao servidor forçando o recarregamento da div de mensagens, conforme abaixo:

```
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, options) {
        if(options.url.toString().split('/')[2] != 'Mensagens')
            exibirMensagens();
    });

 function exibirMensagens() {
        $("#div-mensagens").load('@Url.Action("Mensagens")');
 }



public ActionResult Mensagens()
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_Mensagem.cshtml");
}
```

Não estou muito satisfeito com a solução que foi dada, pois estou forçando uma nova chamada ao servidor sem necessidade.

Gostaria de compartilhar este problema com vocês para buscar a melhor forma de tratar esta situação.

Comment: Quando você detectar que é por AJAX, inclua a partial view da mensagem na partial view da resposta, não funciona ? Ou melhor, porque quando faz por AJAX, ao invés de devolver conteúdo não devolve apenas dados e faz o tratamento no JS ? Assim você pode devolver o resultado da solicitação via JSON juntamente com as mensagens e deixar que o JS transforme os dados em conteúdo e que também exiba as mensagens corretamente, que tal ?

Comment: Outra solução seria separar completamente o serviço de "mensagens" da sua aplicação, e transforma-lo em um serviço de mensagens/notificações assim como do Stack Overflow e do Facebook, que exibe as mensagens conforme elas vão chegando (ai seu controle iria enviar a mensagem ao serviço e o serviço ao usuário). Você pode fazer isso facilmente com SignalR no C# ou com Socket.io no Node.js , mas não sei se deseja levar sua aplicação a esse nível, talvez seja trocar uma bicicleta (força humana, mais devagar, não polui) por uma moto (CNH, combustível, IPVA, etc), entende a analogia ?